# SQL query to find count of 0 and 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have a column name `Allowed`, I want MS SQL query to count of both values 0 and 1

```
Allowed
-------
0
0
0
1
1
1
```

Comment: `select count(Allowed) from tablename group by Allowed`

Answer (score 2):

To get the Allowed count along with the its respective value:

```
SELECT Allowed, COUNT(Allowed) AS AllowedCount
FROM TestTable
GROUP BY Allowed
```

Result:

```
Allowed   AllowedCount
-----------------------
  0          3
  1          3
```

Working SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/500b8/3

To get the Allowed count of both the values 0 and 1:

```
SELECT COUNT(Allowed) AS AllowedCount
FROM TestTable
WHERE Allowed IN (0, 1)
```

Working SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/500b8/5

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select count(Allowed) as count
from yourtable
group by Allowed
```